# Updated model is not reflected in template

Tags: ember.js

I am updating template's model in Controller. The model data is in the form

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": [
    {
        "in1": "val1",
        "in2": "val2"
    },
    {
        "in1": "val3",
        "in2": "val4"
    }
]
}
```

After updating the model through controller, key1 value is refelcted in template. But Key2 values wrapped inside {{#each}} {{/each}} is not get reflected.

JsBin link:
http://jsbin.com/dahehonagufi/3/edit

Kindly assist me what i am doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've played around with your JSBin and it looks like the issue is that, because you were defining the model as a plain JS object, Ember was not able to properly watch / pick up on the model changes.

This version should work (note that I've wrapped the plain objects in `Ember.Object.create({...})`: http://jsbin.com/dahehonagufi/6/edit

There could be a simpler solution but it's not coming to me right now.

Comment: @gomer i need to iterate 10 times my plain js array say it have 10 elements, and create Ember object for each element and keep them in another array. Is it so? tedious and annoying. Any other way to create Ember object from json object

Comment: @Susai If you want your objects to be observable, then yes, you'll have to wrap them in `Ember.Object.create()`.